# Active Directory: Map a domain user with a username from ForeignSecurityPrinciple group and check if user is part of another specific group

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have this problem: we try to authenticate a user against an Active Directory that uses ForeignSecurityPrinciple to map users from different domains.

We have several groups that are stored inside a single domain and users that are coming from different domains.

The problem we have here is that we cannot get the real user name from ForeignSecurityPrinciple.

We tried to use the guidelines from here:

http://www.brandonclaps.com/?p=57

but with no luck.

When we tried to edit the entry for group that had 3 members, we found this next to the member field:

CN = S-1-5-21-other numbers, CN=ForeignSecurityPrinciple; DC=DomainName, DC=local

Do you have other solutions for retrieving the username against Active Directory using ForeginSecurityPrinciple ?

Is there any recommendation for using that?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What is the error you're getting when you run this code? Are you only using the code that was provided in the link above, or do you have anything else you could share? It's really difficult to discern what the issue could be here without a little more information.

Comment: We have managed to find the solution: instead of getting the username from objectSID we used another approach: we firstly get user object from corresponding domain and user object contains objectSid ... then we just get the group from the domain where groups are defined and check if there is such member (with corresponding objectSid).